# luks usb key encryption

Tags: usb, encryption, luks

i am about to install a fresh install of ubuntu and i want to encrypt the disk with luks. but i dont want to type in the password every time i turn the computer on. I want it to be very secure. i found this tutorial - https://www.howtoforge.com/automatically-unlock-luks-encrypted-drives-with-a-keyfile

do i just skip disk encryption when installing, and just follow the tutorial when i have installed ubuntu. and also, does the tutorial generate a encryption key for you?

sorry im just new to encryption, thanks!

Comment: That tutorial still requires manually inputting a password upon boot. `"The keyfile should be stored in the normally encrypted root partition - so you still have to unlock that one. During boot process it will then be used to unlock all the other devices."`